# Split a (Bengali) string by a regex without consuming the delimiter, zero-width forward lookahead not working

Tags: javascript, regex-lookarounds, unicode-escapes

Actually I can't get it to work in English either. I'm looking for an expression that combines two regexes:

```
const string = 'Joe shouted, \"The pitchforks are coming!\"';

zeroWidthSplitter = /(?=e)/g;  //splits before every "e"

string.split(zeroWidthSplitter) == 
    ["Jo", "e shout", "ed, \"Th", "e pitchforks ar", "e coming!"]  //true

wordRegex = /[a-zA-Z]+/g;    // matches all English letters, 
                             // discarding spaces and punctuation

string.match(wordRegex) ==
    ["Joe", "shouted", "The", "pitchforks", "are", "coming"]
```

what I want is a zeroWidthWordDelimiter such that it behaves like splitting with word boundary, keeping spacing and punctuation seperate to words:

```
string.split(/(?:\b)/gm);

//the string is split strictly with words and non-words

0: "Joe"
1: " "
2: "shouted"
3: ", \""
4: "The"
5: " "
6: "pitchforks"
7: " "
8: "are"
9: " "
10: "coming"
11: "!"
```

but I wish to split a string of foreign (Bengali) characters and these characters are not recognised by word boundaries.
 I can group the words successfully, and group the gaps successfully by putting all bengali letters in a [character class]+
Wiktor's suggestion is a big improvement, to separate the characters into a non-capturing group (?:a|b|c|d). This successfully groups words, but loses punctuation.
As does Peter's even slicker Regex `/[^\p{Script=Bengali}]+/u`  which uses [Unicode Property Escapes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Unicode_Property_Escapes)

```js
BengaliString = 'হঠাৎ একটা মেয়ে বাকি দু’জন কে কানে কানে বললো,“আমি যেমন টা করবো তোরা সেরকম আমার সাথে থাকবি ।”' ;

const BengaliRegex = /[ড়ঢ়ঁংঃঅআইঈউঊঋঌএঐওঔকখগঘঙচছজঝঞটঠডঢণতথদধনপফববভমমযরলশষসহািীুূৃৄেৈোৌ্ৎড়ঢ়য়]+/gm ;  //groups words

const BengaliGapsRegex    = /[^ড়ঢ়ঁংঃঅআইঈউঊঋঌএঐওঔকখগঘঙচছজঝঞটঠডঢণতথদধনপফববভমমযরলশষসহািীুূৃৄেৈোৌ্ৎড়ঢ়য়]+/gm ;   //groups gaps

const BengaliDelimiter = /(?=[^ড়ঢ়ঁংঃঅআইঈউঊঋঌএঐওঔকখগঘঙচছজঝঞটঠডঢণতথদধনপফববভমমযরলশষসহািীুূৃৄেৈোৌ্ৎড়ঢ়য়]+)/gm ;
    //zero width but breaks apart many words

const BengaliRegexWiktor = /(?:ড়|ঢ|়|ঁ|ং|ঃ|অ|আ|ই|ঈ|উ|ঊ|ঋ|ঌ|এ|ঐ|ও|ঔ|ক|খ|গ|ঘ|ঙ|চ|ছ|জ|ঝ|ঞ|ট|ঠ|ড|ঢ|ণ|ত|থ|দ|ধ|ন|প|ফ|ব|ব|ভ|ম|ম|য|র|ল|শ|ষ|স|হ|া|ি|ী|ু|ূ|ৃ|ৄ|ে|ৈ|ো|ৌ|্|ৎ|ড়|ঢ়|য়)+/mg
    //groups words perfectly
 
const BengaliSplitterWiktor = /(?=(?:ড়|ঢ|়|ঁ|ং|ঃ|অ|আ|ই|ঈ|উ|ঊ|ঋ|ঌ|এ|ঐ|ও|ঔ|ক|খ|গ|ঘ|ঙ|চ|ছ|জ|ঝ|ঞ|ট|ঠ|ড|ঢ|ণ|ত|থ|দ|ধ|ন|প|ফ|ব|ব|ভ|ম|ম|য|র|ল|শ|ষ|স|হ|া|ি|ী|ু|ূ|ৃ|ৄ|ে|ৈ|ো|ৌ|্|ৎ|ড়|ঢ়|য়)+)/gm ;
    //doesn't group multiple letters using +

const BengaliRegexPeter = /[^\p{Script=Bengali}]+/u ;
   //beautiful! but doesn't keep punctuation and spacing

console.log("Bengali Gaps Regex: " + BengaliString.split(BengaliGapsRegex));
console.log("Regex Delimiter: " + BengaliString.split(BengaliDelimiter));
console.log("Bengali Regex Wiktor: " + BengaliString.match(BengaliRegexWiktor));
console.log("Bengali Splitter Wiktor: "+ BengaliString.split(BengaliSplitterWiktor));
console.log("Regex Peter: " + BengaliString.split(BengaliRegexPeter));
```

Comment: I think it will be hard to help you given that the problem interweaves use of some natural language most here aren't proficient with, with its own rules I assume, with regular expressions. I understand regular expressions, for example, but I can't tell a) how you want those foreign characters split into words b) what that `!` is doing among the other characters and c) why would characters be consumed -- they are merely identified in a regular expression, unless you actually use `String.prototype.split`.

Comment: You should not use a character class for these characters. Use an alternation group, `(?:a|b|c|...|z)`. Only group those chars in a character class that consist of one single byte.

Comment: the ! was a mistake which strangely didn't affect the result.

Comment: thanks Wiktor, I'll give it a go!

Comment: I just don't know the language and do not see what distinct characters  you have got here, otherwise, I could provide an answer.

Comment: @AndreiCleland ... Can you please provide a text and/or even a code snippet where one could play around with the problem you describe? And also could [Unicode Property Escapes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Unicode_Property_Escapes) be of any help ?.. something like ... `"ড়ঢ়ঁংঃঅআইঈউঊঋঌএdfsdfdsঐওঔকখগঘঙচছজঝঞটdsfdsfঠডঢণতথদধনপফববভমমযরলশষসহািীুূৃৄেৈোৌ্ৎড়ঢ়য়".split(/[^\p{Script=Bengali}]+/u)`

Comment: Thanks @Peter Unicode Property Escapes are amazing, though I don't understand at all. Can I combine your regex, /[^\p{Script=Bengali}]+/u, with a regular boundary: /(?:\b)/gm   ? so that it uses bengali letters not English?? Unfortunately the script command doesn't seem to work in the online Regex editors, so that's why I gave up that line of attack. But it's working perfectly in the  browser.

Comment: @AndreiCleland ... Of cause one can combine unicode property escapes. If it was language agnostic one could split e.g. at or before a combination of `\p{Z}` (whitespace or invisible separator) and of `\p{P}` (any kind of punctuation character). But since I neither know Bengali, nor the preferred output of a specifically provided Bengali text, I merely can guess whether something like ... [`BengaliString.split(/(?<=[\p{Z}\p{P}])/gu)`](https://regex101.com/r/II4utG/1) ... or ... [`BengaliString.split(/[\p{Z}\p{P}]/gu)`](https://regex101.com/r/II4utG/2) ... could meet the requirements.

Comment: Thanks again @Peter [Your first regex](https://regex101.com/r/JdD4Y6/2) works best  [\p{Script=Bengali}]+ , but can it be modified to select the in and out boundaries so it is zero width? The other regex works well, but selects English and other scripts

Answer (score 2):

Use this regex pattern for detecting Bangla letters:

```
/[\u0985-\u0994\u0995-\u09a7-\u09a8-\u09ce\u0981\u0982\u0983\u09e6-\u09ef-]/g
```

Comment: `[\u0980-\u09FF]+` this should work precisely.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this very ugly solution (but it works):

```js
////// matches punctuation, digits, spaces, zero-width space and non-breaking
////// space and keeps both: words in one group and punctuation/spaces in the next:

const rxBengaliSplitterKeepAll = /([\u2000-\u206F\u2E00-\u2E7F\\'!"#$%&()*+,\-.\/:;<=>?@\[\]^_`{|}~  ।\d]+)/g;


////// matches all of above but keeps only the words:

const rxKeepOnlyBengaliNoPunctuation = /[\u2000-\u206F\u2E00-\u2E7F\\'!"#$%&()*+,\-.\/:;<=>?@\[\]^_`{|}~  ।\d]+/gm;



        /// PUTS SPANS WITH IDs AROUND EVERY BENGALI WORD 
function createWordSpans( string ){
        // splits and catches all words and all non-words:
  const tempDiv = document.createElement( "div" ) 
  let wordsAndGaps = string.trim().split( rxBengaliSplitterKeepAll );
  if ( wordsAndGaps[ wordsAndGaps.length-1 ] == "" ) wordsAndGaps.pop() ;
  let idNum = 1;    // word counter
  wordsAndGaps.forEach( word => {
    if ( word.length && !word.match( rxKeepOnlyBengaliNoPunctuation )) idNum++
    tempDiv.appendChild( createWordSpan( word, idNum ))
  })
  return tempDiv.innerHTML
}

function createWordSpan( word, idNum ){
  if ( word.length > 0 && !( word.match( rxKeepOnlyBengaliNoPunctuation ))){
            // BUILD A SPAN FOR IT:
    const wordEl = document.createElement( "span" );
    wordEl.innerText = word;
    wordEl.setAttribute( "id", "id" + idNum );
    wordEl.setAttribute( "class", "selectable"+ (idNum % 2));
    return wordEl
  } 
  else {  // if the "word" does have punctuation or spaces:
    const text = document.createTextNode( word )
    return text
  }
}


bengaliString = 'হঠাৎ একটা মেয়ে বাকি দু’জন কে কানে কানে বললো,“আমি যেমন টা করবো তোরা সেরকম আমার সাথে থাকবি ।”' ;
 
const myDiv = document.getElementById( "myDiv" );
myDiv.innerHTML = createWordSpans( bengaliString );
```

```css
.selectable0 {
    background-color: aliceblue;
}
.selectable1 {
    background-color: antiquewhite;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```